# ElasticSearch : Error on char_filter setting

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm encountering an error on elasticSearch when I want to update index' settings to add a char filter which should replace spaces by a "-" on index and search.

This is the error that I have in logs :

> [app][4] received shard failed for [app][4],
>   node[eJuT9n88QIqNC_8fZhmo6A], [P], s[INITIALIZING],
>   unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED],
>   at[2016-04-11T09:53:14.756Z], details[shard failure [failed to create
>   index][IndexCreationException[[app] failed to create index]; nested:
>   ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[token filter [char_filter] must
>   have a type associated with it]; ]]], indexUUID
>   [eQrTAVxGS6uJmiMfKqRxNQ], reason [shard failure [failed to create
>   index][IndexCreationException[[app] failed to create index]; nested:
>   ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[token filter [char_filter] must
>   have a type associated with it]; ]]

This is the way I update my settings :

```
PUT /app/_settings
{
   "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
         "spaces": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "/ /g",
            "replacement": "-"
         }
      },
      "analyzer": {
         "marque_index": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "char_filter": [
               "spaces"
            ],
            "filter": [
               "trim",
               "lowercase"
            ]
         },
         "marque_search": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "char_filter": [
               "spaces"
            ],
            "filter": [
               "trim",
               "lowercase"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My version of ES : 1.7.5

It does two days that I'm stuck with that. I tried everything and based my work on this doc :

[ES pattern replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) and [ES custom analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html)

-- Little update :

What I get when I request my index' settings : `GET /app/_settings`

```
{
   "app": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1460370729368",
            "uuid": "zRfx6USRSfazbLLyIHbqnw",
            "analysis": {
               "char_filter": {
                  "spaces": {
                     "type": "pattern_replace",
                     "pattern": "/ /g",
                     "replacement": "-"
                  }
               },
               "analyzer": {
                  "marque_search": {
                     "type": "custom",
                     "char_filter": [
                        "spaces"
                     ],
                     "filter": [
                        "trim",
                        "lowercase"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                  },
                  "marque_index": {
                     "type": "custom",
                     "char_filter": [
                        "spaces"
                     ],
                     "filter": [
                        "trim",
                        "lowercase"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "version": {
               "created": "1070599"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Everything looks good...

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Those settings work fine for me, provided you close the `app` index first.

Comment: Sure, I'm doing it : `POST /app/_close` => `PUT /app/_settings blabla` => `POST /app/_open`. I can't explain what is happening here :(

Comment: Why didn't you apply those settings directly when creating the index? Can you wipe it out and start over and apply those settings at index creation time? What happens?